# Magento- Multiple Website product prices

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, multicurrency

I am currently running a magento instance with a single website/store with around 3000 products, i need to create another website, with a different base currency.

So for product prices have set the scope of price to be website, but when i run my second website, the price of products comes same as the original one i.e

Website A
Product P-Price $100

Website B

Product P -Price Rs 100

Is there a way which will convert the price for the second website, taking conversion rates and base price as the first one, without doing it pragmatically.

Comment: This is unclear a bit. You wan't it so it P has the price 100$ in website A to see it as about 6000Rs on the second website?

Comment: yes..is there a way to do this..once i have multiple websites setup in admin.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the price to still remain 100$ for product P but on the second website display it as (about) 6000Rs, you need to leave the base currency for the second website as it is...USD.
Just play with the allowed currencies for the second websites. Choose only Rs.
And make sure you fill in a conversion rate in `System->Manage Currency->Rates`.

This way your second website will still use USD as base currency, so the price will be 100$, but you won't see any trace of USD. All prices will be converted to Rs.

Comment: yes but if i leave the second website base currency as USD, i wont be able to accept payment in Rs..or would i?

Comment: @huzefam Arr...good point. I'm not sure about this. I think it depends on the payment method. You have to test it yourself or wait for an other opinion.

Comment: yes that is where i am stuck up, as the payment needs to be processed in USD for one and Rs for another..i can manage to update the prices programatically , but what happens when the conversion rates change in future..

Comment: If you want you can still keep your approach, with different base currencies, but you have to set up a cron to run each night and convert the prices for the second website based on the currency rate.

Comment: also i was planning to accept more than 20+ currencies on the website, so i guess wold have to create 20 websites and update the price of products at each website level..so maybe thought if there is an alternative to it..

Answer (score 0):

I have used this piece of script to run at covert my website prices.

```
<?php
    require_once "app/Mage.php";

    Mage::app();

    $productCollection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array("id","price"))->addStoreFilter(1);
    $fromCur = 'USD'; // currency code to convert from - usually your base currency
    $toCur = 'INR'; // currency to convert to

    foreach($productCollection as $product):
        $_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->setStoreId(2)->load($product->getId());

        $price = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($product->getPrice(), $fromCur, $toCur);

        $_product->setPrice($price); 
        $_product->save();
        $_product=NULL;
    endforeach;

?>
```